# C# MVC vs ASP.NET MVC difference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture, asp.net-mvc-4

I am an intermediate C# developer and taught myself the basics of C# MVC, but not ASP.NET MVC.  I already know classic ASP and ASP.NET though I haven't used them in many years, at least 5, since I mostly do C# desktop development at my job.  The thing is, I now want to migrate all of our existing C# applications to the web..

So, I am going to start looking to hire a new developer but my question is this, since I don't really know ASP.NET MVC specifically would it be smart to look for a C# MVC developer only, since I plan to have all our internal C# apps migrated to the web?  I know that ASP.NET and C#.NET can be used together but I want to try and keep everything uniform. This person will likely have to understand some C# to be able to migrate our internal apps so should I continue looking for a C# MVC developer only or do you think an ASP.NET developer will have no problem?  I imagine there are plenty of ASP.NET MVC developers out there but not as many knowledgable with C#...plus it would help if they understand the not-so-difficult C# written apps when they they migrate to MVC.

Can someone explain the pros/cons or differences between the ASP.NET MVC & C# MVC or what issues I should expect to come across?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by c# mvc?

Comment: They are the same thing.  C# is the language you have used to do your development, but ASP.NET MVC is the framework you used to do it.

Comment: There is nothing c# mvc .only asp.net mvc

Comment: This should be in programmers.stackexchange

Comment: It appears the question is "What is the difference between C# MVC and ASP.NET MVC". I don't think there really is a technology called "C# MVC". All of the stuff about "I'm hiring a new developer" would probably best be removed, as it only serves to make the question more confusing.

Comment: Thanks all.RE: Ryan, I don't use this site much I'm not familiar with programmers.stackexchange but will check on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there is no C# MVC.

**MVC** (Model, View, Controller) is an Architect Pattern.

**ASP.NET MVC** is an implementation of this pattern of Microsoft ASP.NET and you can use C#, VB.Net and other languages to programming on this platform.

You also can build your application using MVC principles (for sample) in a Windows Forms application without any default implementation like ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I try to test for general programming and problem-solving skills.
If a developer cannot quickly pick up a new library or language, I probably don't want to commit to hiring them.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers a question asked

Comment: Thanks, definitely will take this into consideration. I was just worried that if I ask an ASP.NET developer to translate C# code they may become intimidated, if all they've ever done was ASP-type work.

Comment: TankorSmash: You're right; at best it's a half-answer for half of the question. No points for me.